# Calculating the volume of intersection of balls.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, volume

> Let $B(0,1) \subseteq \Bbb{R}^d$ the open unit ball and $x \in \Bbb{R^d}$ such that $|x|>1$.
>
> Let the ball $B_x=B(\frac{1}{2}(|x|-\frac{1}{|x|})\frac{x}{|x|},\frac{1}{2}(|x|+\frac{1}{|x|}))$ in $\Bbb{R}^d$

We obsviously have $|x|+\frac{1}{|x|}>2$

How can i calculate the volume of $B_x \cap B(0,1)$?

Is there a general technique/formula and an article or pdf,for calculating these types of volumes?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The intersection of the two balls will be the union of two spherical caps, so then you need to determine the dimensions and then volume of these caps.

Comment: I have thought of that but i have to find explicitly  the volume of the intersection and i do not know a formula or something else for this..especially in dimension >2

Comment: From your comment it is not clear to me if you read and understood my comment, but proceeding anyway: the volume of a spherical cap is on the Wikipedia article, and finding the dimensions of your caps is a matter of geometry. If you draw a triangle between the two centers and a point on the intersection of the two spheres, you get a triangle with sides $1,r,c$ where $c$ is the distance of the one ball's center to $0$.

Comment: I have seen the wikipedia page you mention,but how can these be generalized in dimension $>3 $?

Comment: If you scroll down there is a [section on hyperspherical caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Hyperspherical_cap).

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake..the article i saw is not on wikipedia...is this : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html...i have not seen the article you mention..thank you for the reference.